# elastic search optimal number of masters

Tags: elasticsearch

We currently have a cluster of 6 data node and one non-data node. Of those, two are currently master eligible. This cluster is on EC2.

What is the optimal number of master nodes, or is there a reason to discriminate at all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A cluster cannot function without a master node. So, the number of master-eligible nodes depends on your tolerance for losing all master nodes.

It might be also helpful to have an odd number of master-eligible nodes and set `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` to be larger than half of the number of master eligible nodes in your cluster. This should significantly reduce chances of your cluster going into split-brain condition.

For example, for a cluster with 3 master-eligible nodes, you can set `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` to 2.

Answer (score 4):

As described in [Elasticsearch Pre-Flight Checklist](http://asquera.de/opensource/2012/11/25/elasticsearch-pre-flight-checklist/), you can set `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` to at least `(N/2)+1` on clusters with `N > 2` nodes.

Where N is the number of eligible master nodes.

Which means in your case, `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 4` eligible master nodes - i.e `(6/2)+1`

Comment: Why did you say "in your case... 2". He mentioned 6 nodes so wouldn't that be 4 based on the formula?

Comment: @philfreo Yes it will be. I'll adjust my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The minimum number of master eligible nodes here is 2. If minimum master nodes is set to 4, the cluster will always be inoperable. It's best to always have more than 2 master eligible nodes for the quorum to work well.

Answer (score 1):

`minimum_master_nodes` (the quorum) should be calculated based on the number of master nodes, not data nodes, Uyi's suggestion would be correct if and only if all of your data nodes are also master eligible nodes.

You should never have 2 master nodes, due to the potential of being in a [split-brain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#split-brain) situation, my suggestion would be, make at least 3 nodes master eligible and set minimum master node to 2.

Another thing to consider is to have smaller but dedicated master nodes, to make sure they are more stable and not under pressure from handling indexing.